# Block Test Lab results from Firebase Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-test-lab

I have a new app which also includes Firebase Analytics. After some work I got it manged to [block Analytics from debug builds](https://medium.com/@rekire/in-short-disable-firebase-crash-reporting-and-analytics-ed3343f92263#.v5o3ezcmx), however I see events from the monkey tests in the cloud which I want to block since they break my statistics for now. Is there any reliable way to achieve that?

Comment: The IP-Ranges can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/overview#testlab_and_mobile_advertising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most reliable scheme is to only test your app using a build/variant against a Firebase project where stats are not important.  I'm assuming your "production" app stats are important and your "dev" stats are not.  We encourage developers to [use multiple projects](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/organizing-your-firebase-enabled-android-app-builds.html) for precisely this reason.

If you absolutely need to test against a production Firebase project, [there are ways to disable Analytics both at build time and run time](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics).

Comment: That reference is nice. I didn't found that yet. That is much simpler then my way to block the analytics code.

Comment: The problem is that the tests are run by Google when you upload to the play store.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to disable Firebase analytics if the 'device under test' is in the Test Lab IP Range.

See my answer here for a Util method that does this.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54954273/114549

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227).