# How to detect app running in Firebase Test Lab on iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-test-lab

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43598250/how-to-detect-running-in-firebase-test-lab) answered this for android: by [checking for firebase.test.lab System.Settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/android-studio#modify_instrumented_test_behavior_for).

But how to detect running inside the firebase test lab in an iOS app? I did not find anything similar for iOS in the [test lab documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/ios/firebase-console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to check that you're running in Firebase Test Lab is to send your own environment variable when you initiate a test. In iOS, there isn't an equivalent to Android's System/Global/Secure settings.

You may either set up the environment variable in your scheme, or modify your .xctestrun file by hand.